# Only do this, IF ajax-load()ed data contains that

Tags: jquery, ajax, getscript

I need to load fragments of content from another html-file into my index.html, into a DIV with ID "#content-main".
This has been done using jquery load().
Since I only do a fragmental load of DIV with class ".fragment", I have to load the scripts from the html-file seperately (jQuery won't load them when using fragmental load).

I do this by using getScript, which works fine as shown here:

```
$('#content-main').load(pageName + " .fragment", function() { 
    $.getScript("js/Magic-init.js");            
});
```

Problem is, I don't want to load/execute the scripts for every html I load content from, just for the ones where a special class is assigned to the loaded DIV.
So I though I could use an if-condition, or maybe a find(), but I canot get it to work.

So how would I add the condition to check what jQuery did load?

This did not work:

```
$('#content-main').load(pageName + " .fragment", function() { 
    if( $('.Magic').length ) {
        $.getScript("js/Magic-init.js");            
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** 
adding the original index.htm and the content.htm to show my structure.

INDEX.htm:

(sorry somehow I cannot add the html-head here, so just add doctype, head & body-tags in your mind. As script, I just add the jquery-1.11.0.min.js in head)

```
<div id="nonFooter">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="menu">
            <h1><a href="index.htm">test</a></h1>

            <hr>

            <nav>
                <ul>                    
                    <li><a href="content.htm" class="ajaxLink">click me to see ajax-loaded content</a></li>                 
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>  <!-- END id=menu -->

        <div id="content-main"></div> <!-- in here comes the AJAX injected content from the clicked ajaxLink -->

    </div> <!-- END id=page -->
</div> <!-- END id=nonFooter -->


<script>
    $(function () {
        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
        <!-- - - - - - - - - AJAX Load Contents & HTML5 History  - - - - - - - - -->
        <!-- - - - - - - - http://www.codemag.com/Article/1301091  - - - - - - - -->            

        function navigateToPage() {
            var pageName = window.location.pathname;
            $('#content-main').load(pageName + " .fragment", function() {   
                if($($('#content-main').html()).find(".Magic").length  > 0) { //delete this line for testing script-loading without if-condition
                    $.getScript("init.js");
                } //delete this line for testing script-loading without if-condition
            });
        }

        $("a.ajaxLink").on('click', function (e) {
            if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var pageName = $(this).attr("href");
                window.history.pushState(null, "", pageName);
                navigateToPage();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

CONTENT.htm

```
<div id="nonFooter">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="menu">
            <h1><a href="index.htm">test</a></h1>

            <hr>

            <nav>
                <ul>                    
                    <li><a href="content.htm" class="ajaxLink">click me to see ajax-loaded content</a></li>                 
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>  <!-- END id=menu -->

        <div id="content-main">
            <div id="gallery-1" class="Magic fragment">
                <div class="imagepos">
                    <p>black text.<br>
                    <span>This text is red when script loaded & link clicked.</span></p>
                </div>                          
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- END id=page -->
</div> <!-- END id=nonFooter -->
```

INIT.js:

```
$('.Magic').find( "span" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('#content-main').load(pageName + " .fragment", function() { 
    if($($('#content-main').html()).find(".Magic").length  > 0) {
        $.getScript("js/Magic-init.js");            
    }
});
```

By the way, make sure your htmls are perfect, cause I have used this syntax countless times and they worked.

Comment: you mean, my version does work for you, or your version?

Comment: would it be a problem when there are more than one classes assigned to the DIV?

Comment: can you post the html after it is loaded?

Comment: it's a bit tricky. The script adds some DIVs and changes classes, so the html looks different. But generally, it's a very straight forward div-structure with some classes and that's it. I'll try to add sth later to my post like before/after, now I have to leave computer for some hours :(

Comment: anyhow I wonder, in the case the script gets executed, where does it show up? I can verify by the changes in behaviour and DIV-structure of the loaded html-data, but when I examine the page with firebug, I can't find the script implemented anywhere in the code ?!

Comment: well I just reduced the whole page to just the absolute necessary, and it still won't do. Now the html is really undeerstandable, and the resulting page is as clear as the initial index. How would I load these 3 files somewhere to show it to you?? I think jsfiddle does not support linking several files and ajax-loading?

Comment: hm not sure why it is still not working. I noticed one thing, the `a` click handler does not return `false` which means, it will navigate you to page `content.html`, have you verified that it is not navigating and just loading?

Answer (score 0):

this does the trick:

```
if($('#content-main').find(".Magic").length) { 
  $.getScript("init.js");
}
```